# What is visual studio 2010 analog for `g++ -E file.cxx`?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, ide, boost-preprocessor

Is there any, can we see results in IDE?

So I try code sample that uses boost preprocessor and [is shown here (!warning - russian)](http://dsukhonin.blogspot.com/2009/11/boostpreprocessor.html):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT(name, seq) DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_I(name, seq)

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_I(name, seq)                   \
struct name {                                          \
    DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_FIELDS(seq)                   \
    \
    template <typename functor>                          \
    void apply(Functor functor) {                        \
    DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_APPLY_FIELDS(functor, seq)  \
    }                                                    \
};

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_EXTRACT_TYPE(tuple)   \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, tuple)

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_EXTRACT_NAME(tuple)   \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, tuple)

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_FIELDS(seq)              \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(                                \
    DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_FIELDS_OP, ~, seq)

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_FIELDS_OP(z, data, el)   \
    DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_EXTRACT_TYPE(el)                    \
    DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_EXTRACT_NAME(el);

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_APPLY_FIELDS(ft, seq)    \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(                                \
    DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_APPLY_FIELDS_OP, ft, seq)

#define DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_ENUM_APPLY_FIELDS_OP(z, ft, el) \
    ft(DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT_EXTRACT_NAME(el));

//this
DEFINE_OUR_STRUCT(first_struct,
    ((int               , id))
    ((std::vector<char> , data))
    )
// shall turn into 
/*
struct first_struct {
    int                   id;
    std::vector<char>     data;

    template <typename Functor>
    void apply(Functor functor) {
        functor(id);
        functor(data);
    }
};
*/
// ...And probably shall not give as many errors as it does...

    int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

My IDE is VS2010 (ultimate), I wonder how to see my code as IDE sees it - meanig with my define turned into code. Can it be done inside IDE, can it be done from VS consol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the Visual Studio compiler from the commandline with `CL /E` to do the equivalent of gcc's `-E` (i.e. preprocessed). I'm not aware of a way to do this from the IDE itself.

As @MooingDuck says, you can output preprocessed source to a configurable file which you can view from the IDE although you can't get the preprocessed output to spool directly to an IDE output window AFAIK.

Comment: In the project properties, there's two options, "preprocess to a file" and "name of preprocessed file"  You have to open the file seperate once its made though

Comment: Well... I found [/P](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6(v=vs.80).aspx) which can be used inside of the project, which works but for presented demo generates 1600 kb .i file in /obj folder e with so many blanks... and VS does not provide hightlightning for it...(

Comment: @myWallJSON: Well the preprocessed output isn't designed to be readable; it's just an intermediate step for the next stage of the compile.